# BI - Sales Fact Table Header and Detail Dimension

Tags: business-intelligence

I have a FactSales table that is down to the line item.

I also have a sales order detail dimension that contains attributes that don't belong in the fact table.

Now, I'm in need of incorporating sales header information into the data mart.

Options:

Create a sales header dimension and place the key in the fact table.

Create a sales header dimension and place the key in the sales order detail dimension.

Incorporate the header info that I need (not a lot) into the sales order detail dimension. (This seems unscalable and a bad design but it's an option so I'm mentioning it)

It seems like option 1 is the best but I would appreciate if someone could shed some light on the pros and cons.

Thank you

Comment: IMHO pption 1 it's ok as long as you don't have any measures on header data (like overall VAT, additional discount...). If you do, you wont be able to display it along with sales order dimension data.

Comment: Have you condidered a degenerate dimension? This might help you decide https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_dimension